# cannot add modules to prestashop footer

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I am writing a theme for Prestashop (1.4) from a design. I have my footer template in the theme which includes this code.

```
    <div id="footer">
        {$HOOK_FOOTER}
    </div>
```

but some modules do not appear when I add them in the backoffice. If I add the payments logos (blockpaymentlogo) there is no output, even though the php file for that module has a `hookFooter()` method.

What should I be looking at?

Comment: Did you try to put an `echo` in the `hookFooter` method of the module to see whether it is executed?

Comment: Good plan. Was frustrated this morning. I found out that i had not set a cms id in the module config. You can write that as an answer and I will accept it if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put an `echo` in the `hookFooter` method of the module to see whether it is executed.